# Alarm manager malfunctioning in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I'm using Alarm Manager in my project. I've set it to repeat for every one hour but it repeats for every 10 sec. I just need to make it for every one hour. Thanks in advance.

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    long retryTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()
            + (60 * 60 * 1000);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, retryTime,
            (60 * 60 * 1000), pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

> SetRepeating Method Parameters :-
>
> TYPE : One of ELAPSED_REALTIME, ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, RTC, or
> RTC_WAKEUP.
>
> TriggerAtMillis : time in milliseconds that the alarm should first go
> off, using the appropriate clock (depending on the alarm type).
>
> IntervalMillis : interval in milliseconds between subsequent repeats
> of the alarm.
> OPERATION  :Action to perform when the alarm goes off;
> typically comes from IntentSender.getBroadcast().

So Change Parameter TriggerAtMillis (in your code Retry): to `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()`

Comment: Thanks for your reply dude. My code is working fine but the problem is my device. It's not working properly. I just restart my device and reinstall my app, it working fine. anyway thanks dude :)